# Filtering Down Component Map using click function react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am currently working on a fun project and I want to know how to do something that has stumped for a bit.

Basically I am using Axios to get my data and then rendering data out in a .map func then I have a click function to show only the data that is corresponding to the ID for example ID 1 has some values that I want to show in another component. How do I do that?

https://j99t7.csb.app/

If you see my sand box and click on one of the ids and see the console / code - this is where I am stuck at.

Cheers,

Dave :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to filter the data, you can use something like:

```
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
```

//onclick

```
setFilteredData(data.filter(element => element.id === id));
```

//jsx return

```
filteredData.map(filteredElement => {
      //loop through elements and display data desired 
})
```

Comment: Lovely thank you!

Comment: Thanks again for this but I can not get it to work can you suggest any more help please?

Comment: The onClick. - setFilteredData(data.filter(element => element.id === id));
 part doesn't make sense / I can not get this to work  :(

Comment: @daveCodesCode filteredData is a secondary variable in order to keep the first one, the real data, intact. 
When you setFilteredData you're just using javascript filter to get the items you want.
After that you just map your way into jsx code.

Comment: Check this fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-dewdney-yz6oe?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you Ricardo :) Marked as answer!

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not a React Master, `onClick` doesn't return `JSX` or `TSX`.

`i.e` where would the returned value be rendered, in most cases, it used as a void function `with no return value`

[image]